# How to Configure Stripe Payment API, for DI within .NET Core Web API application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, stripe-payments

I have been looking everywhere on this and it's surprisingly difficult to get a conclusive or recommended approach to setting up the Stripe API/SDK library for .NET Core.

I have added the nuget package:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="43.16.0" />
```

Now according to the instructions I set my API key like so in the startup.

```
  private static void RegisterStripeClient(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var env = configuration.Get<EnvironmentVariables>();
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = env.STRIPE_API_KEY;
 }
```

Now this key is the key from the test enviroment so it's like this: sk_test_51Oe ...

However I keep getting invalid key when trying to create a subscription!

```
      // Lets see if I can add a subscription for the current user.
  var options = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
  {
      Customer = request.PaymentDetails.CustomerId,
      Items =
      [
          new SubscriptionItemOptions { Price = "price_1Opxxxxxxxx..." }
      ],
  };

  var service = new SubscriptionService();

  var subscription = service.Create(options);
```

I would have thought this would have just worked. Yes the key is fine, I stepped through the debugger and can see the value being assigned just fine.

So what to do and also how should this be registed for DI in program.cs

Thx.

Comment: Do you notice a request id (req_xxx) on the error? Grabbing the Id and reaching out to Stripe Support could help. Also you can look at your Stripe Dashboard log https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs to see if there is a generated request.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid API Key provided: sk_test_...",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
It's definitely hitting there servers, it must be the way I am setting the api key, or something tha'ts just missing from the documentation. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the initialisation code is just the below:

```
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = env.STRIPE_API_KEY;
```

that's it, however I don't know how to use the DI.